# Transfer data from database to Spark using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, sparklyr

I have some data in a database, and I want to work with it in Spark, using *sparklyr*.

I can use a *DBI*-based package to import the data from the database into R

```
dbconn <- dbConnect(<some connection args>)
data_in_r <- dbReadTable(dbconn, "a table")
```

then copy the data from R to Spark using

```
sconn <- spark_connect(<some connection args>)
data_ptr <- copy_to(sconn, data_in_r)
```

Copying twice is slow for big datasets.

How can I copy data directly from the database into Spark?

*sparklyr* has several [`spark_read_*()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/topics/spark_read_csv) functions for import, but nothing database related.  [`sdf_import()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/topics/sdf_copy_to) looks like a possibility, but it isn't clear how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Sparklyr >= 0.6.0**

You can use `spark_read_jdbc`.

**Sparklyr < 0.6.0**

I hope there is a more elegant solution out there but here is a minimal example using low level API:

- Make sure that Spark has access to the required JDBC driver, for example by adding its coordinates to `spark.jars.packages`. For example with PostgreSQL (adjust for current version) you could add:

  ```
  spark.jars.packages org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212
  ```

  to `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`
- Load data and register as temporary view:

  ```
  name <- "foo"

  spark_session(sc) %>% 
    invoke("read") %>% 
    # JDBC URL and table name
    invoke("option", "url", "jdbc:postgresql://host/database") %>% 
    invoke("option", "dbtable", "table") %>% 
    # Add optional credentials
    invoke("option", "user", "scott") %>%
    invoke("option", "password", "tiger") %>% 
    # Driver class, here for PostgreSQL
    invoke("option", "driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") %>% 
    # Read and register as a temporary view
    invoke("format", "jdbc") %>% 
    invoke("load") %>% 
    # Spark 2.x, registerTempTable in 1.x
    invoke("createOrReplaceTempView", name)
  ```

  You can pass multiple `options` at once using an `environment`:

  ```
  invoke("options", as.environment(list(
    user="scott", password="tiger", url="jdbc:..."
  )))
  ```
- Load temporary view with `dplyr`:

  ```
  dplyr::tbl(sc, name)
  ```
- Be sure to read about further JDBC options, with focus on `partitionColumn`, `*Bound` and `numPartitions`.
- For additional details see for example [How to use JDBC source to write and read data in (Py)Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30983982) and [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188295/6910411)