# How to load data at Spark Dataframe in each Worker to prevent loading huge data to Master node

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I can read data from Oracle Database in Master node using this code:

```
 val spark = SparkSession
            .builder
            .master("local[4]")
            .config("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
            .config("spark.executor.cores", 4)
            .config("spark.task.cpus",1)
            .appName("Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
            .getOrCreate()

 val jdbcDF = spark.read
              .format("jdbc")
              .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:orcldb")
              .option("dbtable", "table")
              .option("user", "orcl")
              .option("password", "********")
              .load()
```

Then I can repartition the Dataframe among Workers:

```
  val test = jdbcDF.repartition(8,col("ID_Col"))
  test.explain
```

My issue is that my data is huge and they cannot fit on the Master RAM. As a result of that I want each node read its own data separately. I am wondering if there is any way to read data from database in every Worker and load them to Spark Dataframe. In fact, I want to load data to Spark Dataframe in each Worker Node separately using Scala or Python.

Would you please guide me how I can do that?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why spark is slower when compared to sqoop , when it comes to jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288481/why-spark-is-slower-when-compared-to-sqoop-when-it-comes-to-jdbc)

Comment: Do you want each worker to read in data in an effort to speed up reading, or just so there is a copy of the data on each worker? If the latter, check out `broadcast`.

Comment: Afaik it does not go via the master.

Comment: Dear @JarrodBaker thank you for your answer, I do want each worker to read data to speed up reading; moreover, I have huge data that all of them cannot be in one node ( I mean Master here). As long as, I know, Master read data and use ```broadcast``` to share data among nodes. It is not what I want.

Comment: @thebluephantom, would you please explain more? Thank you.

Comment: It would be a bad design if it went thru the master

Comment: @thebluephantom, if you mean if all data load to the Master node, it is bad design. I know that and want to load data via each Worker.

Comment: But that is what happens any way, so what is the point?

Comment: Data is read by just one worker by default, if you need to paralellize, see the link

Comment: @thebluephantom, you mean, we cannot change it?

Comment: Dear @AlexOtt, what link do you mean? Can we change that data read by all Workers?

Comment: Look try reading the docs first.

Comment: first link in this discussion

Comment: Read up on local

Answer (score 1):

With `local` you do `not have a Resource Mgr` like YARN. You have `no Workers`, but you can run stuff in parallel provided `local[n]` set suitably on the same machine with N cores.

You will not be loading to the Master if you follow advice of Alex Ott and read up.

You can improve speed of loading by using parameters `lowerBound, upperBound, numPartitions` when reading data with `spark.read.jdbc`, using the `Cores` instead of `Executors` on Workers. That is what local means and how Spark works.

If you need to partition otherwise, you need to then do a subsequent re-partition.

If you have enough memory ***and disk***, you will be slower but it will process.

Comment: Dear @thebluephantom, thank you for your answer. I read the link according to Alex Ott advice. Would you please guide me if I can use ```lowerBound``` and ```upperBound``` in each Worker node with different values? I mean each Worker has its own ```lowerBound``` and ```upperBound```.

Comment: See https://medium.com/@radek.strnad/tips-for-using-jdbc-in-apache-spark-sql-396ea7b2e3d3

Comment: How did it all go?

Comment: the column type is String. I must distribute data base on that String column. I should convert String column to Integer, in a way that the data meaning does not change.

Comment: That is may be not possible. I would select another column that is int, dte or ts and then repartition.

Comment: the String column is very important to distribute data base on it. So, I must find a way to convert it to Integer.

Comment: No, not really, as you can use something else and then re-partition. That seems to be a hard thing to follow but it ain't that bad.