# DataFrame numPartitions default value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read something from a Database table using JDBC:

```
val df = spark.read.jdbc("<database url>", "<some table name>", <some DbProperties>)
```

and then write it to another database:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("<other database url>", "<same table name>", <some DbProperties>)
```

1. If we do not specify `numPartitions` option in the Db Properties, what will be the default value for `numPartitions` Spark uses to read the table from Database into `df`?
2. If I want to write the above `df` into another table of another database, if I still don't specify `numPartitions`, will there be parallel connections created while writing to the Database?
3. Suppose while reading I have given `numPartitions` as 8, while writing this `df` onto the target DB, will the `numPartitions = 8` still be valid without me explicitly specifying it while writing?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43150694/partitioning-in-spark-while-reading-from-rdbms-via-jdbc

Answer (score 3):

If you don't specify either {`partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions`} or {`predicates`} Spark will use a single executor and create a single non-empty partition. All data will be processed using a single transaction and reads will be neither distributed nor parallelized.

See also:

- [How to optimize partitioning when migrating data from JDBC source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52603131/6910411)
- [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188295/6910411)

Please check the spark docs for more information on spark JDBC integration

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

Comment: Ok, suppose I gave `numPartitions` while reading the `DataFrame`, will the same `numPartitions` be used while writing the same `df` (without explicitly specifying it while writing) (Qn. #3)?

Comment: When you run df.write, each of the original partitions in df is written independently. but if you also add ```numPartitions``` as a best practice.

Comment: Ok so that means the same `numPartitions` is retained while writing to the database without me explicitly specifying it, correct?