# Does spark predicate pushdown work with JDBC?

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

According to [this](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/02/17/introducing-dataframes-in-spark-for-large-scale-data-science.html)

> Catalyst applies logical optimizations such as predicate pushdown. The
>   optimizer can push filter predicates down into the data source,
>   enabling the physical execution to skip irrelevant data.

Spark supports push down of predicates to the data source.
Is this feature also available / expected for JDBC?

(From inspecting the DB logs I can see it's not the default behavior right now - the full query is passed to the DB, even if it's later limited by spark filters)

**MORE DETAILS**

Running Spark 1.5 with PostgreSQL 9.4

code snippet:

```
from pyspark import SQLContext, SparkContext, Row, SparkConf
from data_access.data_access_db import REMOTE_CONNECTION

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

url = 'jdbc:postgresql://{host}/{database}?user={user}&password={password}'.format(**REMOTE_CONNECTION)
sql = "dummy"

df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table=sql)
df = df.limit(1)
df.show()
```

SQL Trace:

```
< 2015-09-15 07:11:37.718 EDT >LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3                                                                                                                      
< 2015-09-15 07:11:37.771 EDT >LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE 1=0                                                                                                                   
< 2015-09-15 07:11:37.830 EDT >LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT c.oid, a.attnum, a.attname, c.relname, n.nspname, a.attnotnull OR (t.typtype = 'd' AND t.typnotnull), pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.a
drelid) LIKE '%nextval(%' FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid) JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attribute a ON (c.oid = a.attrelid) JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON (a.a
tttypid = t.oid) LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d ON (d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum) JOIN (SELECT 15218474 AS oid , 1 AS attnum UNION ALL SELECT 15218474, 3) vals ON (c.oid = vals.oid
 AND a.attnum = vals.attnum)                                                                                                                                                                            
< 2015-09-15 07:11:40.936 EDT >LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SET extra_float_digits = 3                                                                                                                      
< 2015-09-15 07:11:40.964 EDT >LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT "id","name" FROM dummy
```

I would expect that the last select will include a `limit 1` clause - but it doesn't

Comment: Just adding the limit (or other filters ) in the SQL code itself

Comment: Did you got it working to get the where clause to be passed to the pushed filters for postgres?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Spark DataFrames support predicate push-down with JDBC sources but term *predicate* is used in a strict SQL meaning. It means it covers only `WHERE` clause. Moreover it looks like it is limited to the logical conjunction (no `IN` and `OR` I am afraid) and simple predicates.

Everything else, like limits, counts, ordering, groups and conditions is processed on the Spark side. One caveat, already covered on SO, is that `df.count()` or `sqlContext.sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df")` is translated to `SELECT 1 FROM df` and requires both substantial data transfer and processing using Spark.

Does it mean it is a lost cause? Not exactly. It is possible to use an arbitrary subquery as a `table` argument. It is less convenient than a predicate pushdown but otherwise works pretty well:

```
n = ... # Number of rows to take
sql = "(SELECT * FROM dummy LIMIT {0}) AS tmp".format(int(n))
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table=sql)
```

**Note**:

This behavior may be improved in the future, once Data Source API v2 is ready:

- [SPARK-15689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689)
- [SPIP: Data Source API V2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n_vUVbF4KD3gxTmkNEon5qdQ-Z8qU5Frf6WMQZ6jJVM/edit)