# Spark SQL on Postgresql JSONB data

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The current Postgresql version (9.4) supports *json* and *jsonb* data type as described in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

For instance, JSON data stored as *jsonb* can be queried via SQL query:

```
SELECT jdoc->'guid', jdoc->'name'
FROM api 
WHERE jdoc @> '{"company": "Magnafone"}';
```

As a Sparker user, is it possible to send this query into Postgresql via JDBC and receive the result as DataFrame?

What I have tried so far:

```
val url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=foo&password=bar"
val df = sqlContext.load("jdbc",
  Map("url"->url,"dbtable"->"mydb", "driver"->"org.postgresql.Driver"))
df.registerTempTable("table")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT data->'myid' FROM table")
```

But sqlContext.sql() was unable to understand the *data->'myid'* part in the SQL.

Comment: I think I am one step closer:  I can incorporate the desired postgresql SQL in a FROM clause of SQL and supply it as 'dbtable' when I run sqlContext.load, e.g.:  val df = sqlContext.load(..., "dbtable"->"(SELECT data->'myid' FROM table) AS foo")

Comment: Combining with the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460496/from-postgres-jsonb-into-spark-jsonrdd  I think I have my problem solved.  But any other advice is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to query `json` / `jsonb` fields dynamically from Spark `DataFrame` API. Once data is fetched to Spark it is converted to string and is no longer a queryable structure (see: [SPARK-7869](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7869)).

As you've already discovered you can use `dbtable` / `table` arguments to pass a subquery directly to the source and use it to extract fields of interest. Pretty much the same rule applies to any non-standard type, calling stored procedures or any other extensions.