# More than one hour to execute pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take(4)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running spark 1.6 on 3 VMs (i.e. 1x master; 2x slaves) all with 4 cores and 16GB RAM.

I can see the workers registered on spark-master webUI.

I want to retrieve data from my Vertica database to work on it. As I didn't manage to run complex queries I tried dummy queries to understand. We consider here an easy task.

My code is:

```py
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='xxxx', dbtable='xxx', user='xxxx', password='xxxx').load()
four = df.take(4)
```

And the output is (note: I replace with `@IPSLAVE` the slave VM IP:Port):

```
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: take at <stdin>:1
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (take at <stdin>:1) with 1 output partitions
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (take at <stdin>:1)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at take at <stdin>:1), which has no missing parents
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.4 KB, free 5.4 KB)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.6 KB, free 7.9 KB)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on @IPSLAVE (size: 2.6 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at take at <stdin>:1)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, @IPSLAVE, partition 0,PROCESS_LOCAL, 1922 bytes)
16/03/08 13:50:41 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on @IPSLAVE (size: 2.6 KB, free: 511.5 MB)
16/03/08 15:02:20 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 4299240 ms on @IPSLAVE (1/1)
16/03/08 15:02:20 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/03/08 15:02:20 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (take at <stdin>:1) finished in 4299.248 s
16/03/08 15:02:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: take at <stdin>:1, took 4299.460581 s
```

As you can see it take a reaaaaaally long time.
My table is actually quite big (stores around 220 millions lines, 11 fields each) but such a query would be quite instantly executed using "normal" sql (e.g. pyodbc).

I guess I am missunderstanding/missusing Spark, would you have so ideas or advice to make it work better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While Spark supports a limited predicate pushdown over JDBC all other operations, like limit, group, aggregations are performed internally. Unfortunately it means that `take(4)` will fetch data first and then apply the `limit`. In other words your database will execute (assuming no projections an filters) something equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

and the rest will handled by Spark. There are some optimizations involved (in particular Spark [evaluates partitions iteratively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54746461/) to obtain number of records requested by `LIMIT`) but it still quite inefficient process compared to database-side optimizations.

If you want to push `limit` to the database you'll have to do it statically using subquery as a `dbtable` parameter:

```py
(sqlContext.read.format('jdbc')
    .options(url='xxxx', dbtable='(SELECT * FROM xxx LIMIT 4) tmp', ....))
```

```scala
sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
  "url"     -> "xxxx",
  "dbtable" -> "(SELECT * FROM xxx LIMIT 4) tmp",
))
```

Please note that an alias in subquery is mandatory.

**Note**:

This behavior may be improved in the future, once Data Source API v2 is ready:

- [SPARK-15689](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15689)
- [SPIP: Data Source API V2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1n_vUVbF4KD3gxTmkNEon5qdQ-Z8qU5Frf6WMQZ6jJVM/edit)

Comment: Interesting. I'll work on it and come back to you to validate the anwser if all is ok :)
Thx!

Comment: @zero323 Should the character after `tmp` be `'` instead? The Scala example works with `sqlContext.read.jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://example.com;databaseName=local;user=debug;password=debug", "(SELECT TOP 5 * FROM ExampleTable) tmp", new java.util.Properties)`

Comment: @RăzvanPanda Yes, it should. Fixed, thanks Options work in Scala as well.

Comment: @zero323 It seems that using a filter is not translated to the database specific SQL either :(

Comment: @RăzvanPanda All depends on a type of a filter. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/32585936/1560062 Is it what you mean? _is limited to the logical conjunction_ - in particular.

Comment: It seems that this is not solved yet https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22388