# Why does SPARK \PYSPARK compute everything even if result is accessed with limit command?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have mysql table stored in dataframe_mysql

```
dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(...
dataframe_mysql.registerTempTable('dataf')
groupedtbl=sqlContext.sql("""SELECT job_seq_id,first(job_dcr_content) as firststage,last(job_dcr_content) as laststage,
                          first(from_stage) as source, last(from_stage) as target , count(jid) as noofstages from dataf group by job_seq_id having count(jid)>1""" )



from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
func1 = udf(fu1, StringType())
func2= udf(fu2, StringType())
res1=groupedtbl.withColumn('dcol',func1(groupedtbl.firststage,groupedtbl.lastage,groupedtbl.job_seq_id))
res2=res1.withColumn('lcol',func2(res1.dcol,res1.job_seq_id))
```

For the above code I see that even I issue a limit command:

```
lb=res2.limit(2).collect()
```

or the following command to only get results of one record:

```
labels.filter(res2.job_seq_id==5843064)
```

Instead of just working to get the two results in the first query or a single result in the second , it does a lot of unnecessary computations on other rows which wastes times even if only two rows are required. I can see this from the internal logs then even for just fetching two rows its computing 100s of rows and then retrieving the two result rows from them. I though that the DAG mechanism should've handle this but it seems it does not , am I wrong in this observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different problems here. Some are related to the data source you use, other to the query and finally there some introduced by using Python UDFs with Spark < 2.0.0.

Step by step:

- with JDBC data source the only the simple predicates are pushed-down to the source. It means only conditions which are inside primary `WHERE` clause (not inside `HAVING` or other computed fields). Everything else including aggregations and limits happens inside Spark (see [Does spark predicate pushdown work with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32573991/1560062), [More than one hour to execute pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35869884/1560062)).
- without explicit partitioning Spark has no apriori knowledge about data distribution. It means that any code that requires data aggregation will have to access all records. As a result `limit` clause with aggregation can exist only after aggregation in the execution plan. This means that:

  ```
  res2.limit(2)
  ```

  cannot be optimized.
- PySpark UDF in Spark < 2.0.0 introduce implicit breakpoints in the execution plan:

  ```
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf

  options = ...
  df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(**options).load()

  df.printSchema()
  ## root
  ##  |-- x: integer (nullable = true)
  ##  |-- y: integer (nullable = true)
  ```

  You can see that predicate is pushed down if there is no `BatchPythonEvaluation`

  ```
  df.groupBy("x").sum("y").where(col("x") > 2).explain()
  ## == Physical Plan ==
  ## TungstenAggregate(key=[x#182], functions=[(sum(cast(y#183 as bigint)),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[x#182,sum(y)#192L])
  ## +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(x#182,200), None
  ##    +- TungstenAggregate(key=[x#182], functions=[(sum(cast(y#183 as bigint)),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[x#182,sum#197L])
  ##       +- Filter (x#182 > 2)
  ##          +- Scan JDBCRelation(...,point,[Lorg.apache.spark.Partition;@61ee5d1a,{...})[x#182,y#183] PushedFilters: [GreaterThan(x,2)]
  ```

  but is not when add `UDF` call, even though output is not used

  ```
  identity = udf(lambda x: x)

  df.groupBy("x").sum("y").withColumn("foo", identity(col("x"))).where(col("x") > 2).explain()
  == Physical Plan ==
  ## Project [x#182,sum(y)#214L,pythonUDF#216 AS foo#215]
  ## +- Filter (x#182 > 2)
  ##    +- !BatchPythonEvaluation PythonUDF#<lambda>(x#182), [x#182,sum(y)#214L,pythonUDF#216]
  ##       +- TungstenAggregate(key=[x#182], functions=[(sum(cast(y#183 as bigint)),mode=Final,isDistinct=false)], output=[x#182,sum(y)#214L])
  ##          +- TungstenExchange hashpartitioning(x#182,200), None
  ##             +- TungstenAggregate(key=[x#182], functions=[(sum(cast(y#183 as bigint)),mode=Partial,isDistinct=false)], output=[x#182,sum#219L])
  ##                +- Scan JDBCRelation(...,point,[Lorg.apache.spark.Partition;@61ee5d1a,{...})[x#182,y#183]
  ```

  This behavior has been optimized in Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: thanks, can you please answer the related question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584185/how-to-reduce-multiple-json-tables-stored-in-a-column-of-an-rdd-to-a-single-rd

Comment: @stackit If I may suggest you should start [accepting  the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) first :) You have quite a few opened questions which have good answers just asking for  that. Regarding linked question it is not clear for me what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: O ya I have accepted , you can comment there as to what I need to explain more , thanks!