# Bit value process in Spark & Postgresql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I try write Spark SQL with `bit()`, it result in an error.

### Code

```
val tpos_dfr = sqlContext.sql("SELECT idcustomer, quantity, CASE WHEN quantity < 0 THEN 1::bit(1) ELSE 0::bit(1) END as isthisreturn FROM pointofsale WHERE iddataloadmanager = 10 and quantity <> 0")
```

### Error

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
>   extraneous input 'quantity' expecting {, ',', 'FROM', 'WHERE', GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 122)

Comment: `sqlContext.sql` creates Spark SQL query, not a PostgreSQL one.

Comment: @zero323, is it possible to execute PostgresSQL with any other method

Comment: Statically. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38729672 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/35870245/1560062 for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean expression, and use the resulting boolean value instead of a bit, so try

```sql
SELECT 
    idcustomer, 
    quantity, 
    quantity < 0 as isthisreturn 
  FROM 
    pointofsale 
  WHERE
    iddataloadmanager = 10 and quantity <> 0
```

then a boolean data type should appear, if you call `printSchema()` on the data frame.