# How to connect to mysql using spark-scala and fetch data in dataframe

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala; The following code, is not printing the values from the df and spark is not stopped it still continues even after 1/2 hour of running this code.

```
    import java.sql.DriverManager
    import java.sql.Connection
    import org.apache.spark._
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

    object MysqlTest {

     def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val prop = new java.util.Properties()
       val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MysqlDataLoad").setMaster("local")
       val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
       val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

       prop.put("user", "***")

       prop.put("password", "*****")

       val url = "jdbc:mysql://acb-cluster.cluster-cfdz.us-wt-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/gsl"

       val df: DataFrame = sqlcontext.read.jdbc(url, "test_20160930_result_prop_alpha", prop)

       df.createOrReplaceTempView("gsl")

// Create dataframe of required columns from GSL table

       println("********* Data For GSL **********")

       val dataFrame2 = sqlcontext.sql("select * from gsl limit 10")

       dataFrame2.show()

       sc.stop()
      }

    }
```

Logs :

```
7/05/31 12:30:51 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 41593.
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.0.132:41593
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.132, 41593, None)
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.0.132:41593 with 1407.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.132, 41593, None)
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.132, 41593, None)
17/05/31 12:30:51 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.132, 41593, None)
17/05/31 12:30:52 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/home/vna/spark_workspace/sz-dw-etl/spark-warehouse/'.
17/05/31 12:30:57 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: gsl
********* Data For GSL **********17/05/31 12:30:57 INFO SparkSqlParser: Parsing command: select * from gsl limit 10

17/05/31 12:30:57 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 320.985934 ms
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: collect at MysqlTest.scala:34
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (collect at MysqlTest.scala:34) with 1 output partitions
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (collect at MysqlTest.scala:34)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at collect at MysqlTest.scala:34), which has no missing parents
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 14.8 KB, free 1407.3 MB)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 6.2 KB, free 1407.3 MB)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.0.132:41593 (size: 6.2 KB, free: 1407.3 MB)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at collect at MysqlTest.scala:34)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5723 bytes)
17/05/31 12:30:58 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
```

EDIT : By fetching another smaller table from the database, this is returning results.

Not sure why even though I limit my query to 10 records, it still needs to  fail.

Since I am running a spark cluster on my local ( 12 gb machine) Does it need more memory to operate? All I am trying to run, is a single 10 record query. ( Running this by SCALA IDE)

More details of the table I am trying to fetch is : its 44 gb, has 100000000 records. But my query clearly limits it to fetch 10 records without any kind of sort.

Comment: Can you change `setMaster("local")` to `setMaster("local[*]")`? `local` gives you 1 core for execution while `local[*]` will take as much as available.

Comment: Can you also make sure you can access `jdbc:mysql://acb-cluster.cluster-cfdz.us-wt-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/gsl` using MySQL-specific tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [More than one hour to execute pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take(4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869884/more-than-one-hour-to-execute-pyspark-sql-dataframe-take4)

Comment: I can connect to that db through mysql workbench from my system;

Comment: If it was a connection issue, shouldnt it timeout

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this :

```
  val properties = new Properties()
  properties.put("user", "root")
  properties.put("password", "123456")
  
  val url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"

  val df = spark.read.jdbc(url,"actor",properties = properties)
```

Make sure the connector is loaded.

```
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.49"
```