# spark access first n rows - take vs limit

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, limit

I want to access the first 100 rows of a spark data frame and write the result back to a CSV file.

Why is `take(100)` basically instant, whereas

```
df.limit(100)
      .repartition(1)
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .option("header", true)
      .option("delimiter", ";")
      .csv("myPath")
```

takes forever.
I do not want to obtain the first 100 records per partition but just any 100 records.

Why is `take()` so much faster than `limit()`?

Comment: So, you can use `take(100)` indeed; what is the question?

Comment: Why take is so much faster than limit.

Comment: Indeed I could, but so far have not seen a way to create a df of the local array to use Sparks nice CSV handling capabilities. Limit should just provide this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because predicate pushdown is currently not supported in Spark, see [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35870245/4629950).

Actually, take(n) should take a really long time as well. I just tested it, however, and get the same results as you do - take is almost instantaneous irregardless of database size, while limit takes a lot of time.

Comment: Collect only works in spark dataframes. When I collect first 100 rows it is instant and data resides in memory as a regular list. Collect in sparks sense is then no longer possible.

Comment: You are right of course, I forgot take returns a list. I just tested it, and get the same results - I expected both take and limit to be slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869884/more-than-one-hour-to-execute-pyspark-sql-dataframe-take4?noredirect=1&lq=1 <- This question however explicitely states that others have problems with `take()` as well - which version of pyspark are you using?

Comment: Spark scala 2.2

Answer (score 63):

Although it still is answered, I want to share what I learned.

```
myDataFrame.take(10)
```

-> **results in an Array of Rows.**
This is an action and performs collecting the data (like collect does).

```
myDataFrame.limit(10)
```

-> **results in a new Dataframe.**
This is a transformation and does not perform collecting the data.

I do not have an explanation why then limit takes longer, but this may have been answered above. This is just a basic answer to what the difference is between take and limit.

Comment: The difference between action and transformation is correct, but that does not explain why limit should take longer than take (once the plan executes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use take(n) to limit the data. Adding the complete code with output in the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Limit() will not work in partition, so it will take more time to execute

Answer (score 0):

limit work for me:

```
limitDF= df.limit(5)
```

Even better approach is limit your data with filter

```
filterDF= df.filter("name = 'jitendra'").limit(5)
```

Answer (score -8):

`.take()` could be the answer, but I used a simple head command like below

```
df.head(3)
```

`.take()` did not work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an answer, it's more a feeling ...