# Performance comparison with take(10) vs limit(10).collect()

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with billion records and I wanted to take 10 records out of it.

Which is the better and faster approach?

`df.take(10)` or `df.limit(10).collect()`?

Answer (score 7):

Both the methods will result in the same performance, simply due to the fact that **their implementation is the same**.

From Spark implementation on [github](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala)

```
def take(n: Int): Array[T] = head(n)
```

While the implementation of head is:

```
def head(n: Int): Array[T] = withAction("head", limit(n).queryExecution)(collectFromPlan)
```

As you can see, head is implemented exactly by using `limit`+`collect`.

Thus they result in the same performance, the difference you measured must be random variation, try to run the experiment many times to overcome it.

Comment: Their implementation are not the same, one "by triggering query execution"

Comment: @lssilva You should compare take(i.e. head) to limit + collect, limit does return a new dataset as it is not an action

Comment: @lssilva a) this issue regards Python, not Scala. b) This is exactly the fix where take(n) was replaced by limit+collect, examine the pull request

Comment: You are right, there seems that in the past they had different implementation but this change synchronized it: https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/91f4b6f2db12650dfc33a576803ba8aeccf935dd#diff-7a46f10c3cedbf013cf255564d9483cd

Answer (score 0):

Spark does lazy evolution. so it doesn't matter which API do you use both will give you the same result with same performance.

Comment: The physical query plan chosen has nothing to do with lazy evaluation or not.

Answer (score -1):

Use take(10), it should be instantaneous.

```
myDataFrame.take(10) //Action
df.limit(10) //Transformation
```

Reference: [spark access first n rows - take vs limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46832394/spark-access-first-n-rows-take-vs-limit)

Comment: But in my case I can see df.limit(10).collect() is a bit faster. My assumption is take(10) from the billion record dataframe is a challenging thing.But cutting of dataframe to 10 records and collecting is better.

Comment: And also adding one more point..Even though if we give take(10) again it is internally using Limit(10) with some other function