# Spark SQL - DataFrameReader load method with where condition

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use `DataFrameReader.load("table name")` to load the `hive` table records and return as `DataFrame`.

But i dont want to load the entire records, i wanted to fetch only the records with specific date (which is one of the field in a hive table).

If i add the where condition in the returned DataFrame, will it load the entire table first then `filter` the records based on date?

Because the hive tables are huge and it is partitioned based on date field.

Basically i want to achieve `select * from table where date='date'` using load method without loading the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of Spark support feature called "predicate push-down". It does exactly what you want: pushes, where it possible, SQL clauses WHERE  into source. I'm not sure if predicate push-down works now with Hive data source (it works for parquet, JDBC and some others sources).
See also [Does spark predicate pushdown work with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573991/does-spark-predicate-pushdown-work-with-jdbc)