# Why are trees used in catalyst optimizer?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know what is the need for trees in Catalyst optimizer and why are they used. What type of values do  hold throughout the execution of a Spark application?

Answer (score 1):

[This post gives some flavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197504/catalyst-optimizer-phases?rq=2) but trees are pretty much the standard way to model a program.  Each spark sql is exactly that, a program waiting to happen.

This starts from simple things like

```sql
a != b and c > (a + 5)
```

which becomes:

```scala
 And(Not(EqualTo(a,b)), GreaterThan(c, Add(a, 5)))
```

That's a tree of Expression's.  These in turn need to be 'run', which means you need a plan to run them.  The Plan's are a different type of tree which can contain the expression trees.

When you do dataframe.explain(true) you see an tree - that's the chain of plan evaluation shown in the above link.  Each plan change represents a series of optimisation steps that transform the plan tree, which could include simplifying expressions, removing duplicate expressions, swapping out faster versions etc.

Finally the actual physical plan will be executed, it's at this stage the tree view may disappear, particularly the Expressions if they are compiled out.

For any more detailed answer you'll have to ask a more specific question but as you note it's tree's of Scala case classes all the way down.

There are quite a few blogs on the subject but the best way to learn it is to look at the source code, find something interesting and look for a blog or at the change / jira history to help explain the why.

Comment: Can you please share, if any, references that answer why trees are the standard way to model a program?

Comment: And at any point in time do trees hold the data that is being processed? Or are trees only used to come up with the execution plan?

Comment: The trees _can_ contain data, e.g. caching, or values e.g. literals, or state (e.g. monotonically incrementing etc.)  Again at this level you should look at the source code.
Re trees, as you are using python see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/parser.html), I think it'd be more interesting for you to find parsers / compilers which do not use trees.