# What is null propagation in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I got to know from this [blog](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html#:%7E:text=pushdown%2C%20projection%20pruning%2C-,null%20propagation,-%2C%20Boolean%20expression%20simplification) that one of the optimization that Spark applies is called Null propagation. What does null propagation mean in the context of dataframes?

Comment: `NullPropagation` is the handling of fields that contain nullable values like empty string, `0`, `''` empty string and that's all I know about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

[The Source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2aa06fcf1607bbad9e09649e587493032e739e35/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/expressions.scala#L802) is the best place to look for information like this.

In short it handles special cases where having a null value literal would make whole trees statically evaluate.  Line [822 here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2aa06fcf1607bbad9e09649e587493032e739e35/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/expressions.scala#L822) has the following rule expression transformation:

```
case IsNull(c) if !c.nullable => Literal.create(false, BooleanType)
```

i.e. if the user has an sql expression "isnull(x)" and x can never be null, then you can replace that expression with "false" directly, you would never need to evaluate the "x" expression here.  Note that doesn't mean it wasn't evaluated elsewhere in the Projection expressions.

DataFrame's are programs describing an execution of expressions and plans using those expressions, I've already provided an explanation you've not yet accepted to [why trees are used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77114760/1028537).