# sqoop vs Spark for data ingestion

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

If I run a sqoop query over RDBMS, say "select id,name from customer where country='US'". In this case sqoop will run the query in RDBMS and fetch only the filtered record which will then be split across to number of mappers we defined.

I want to understand how it will work if run the same query in spark over RDBMS? Filtration (country=US) will happen in RDBMS side or in spark memory? My understanding is filtration should happen in RDBMS but some articles say that filtration will happen in spark memory after fetching all records. Please clarify.

Comment: How about trying it out and look at your database logs to see if the `WHERE` query is included or not?

Comment: Or, search SO for an answer? This is rather old but still a good start : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573991/does-spark-predicate-pushdown-work-with-jdbc

Comment: Quality is going down