# Narrow AWS Glue data to prevent entire dataset pulled

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

at the moment, aws glue grabs data from by postgres database based on the view name provided- and inserts into redshift. One of our database is very big, is there a way to have the aws glue job query the view with a where clause, this way we can grab by last date the job ran so we aren't pulling all the data that is already in redshift.

Comment: Can you give some more info about your setup? Why don't Glue bookmarks work for you? Under the hood, Glue runs Spark so it should also be easy to use pushdown predicates from pyspark or spark script.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/programming-etl-connect-bookmarks.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573991/does-spark-predicate-pushdown-work-with-jdbc

Comment: @bzu so I have all my data stored in a postgres database. AWS glue grabs that data, stores it in s3 bucket, then we have a loader that moves that data to redshift. We are trying to pervent s3 from getting a ton of extra data when they've already been uploaded.