# How to use SQL query to define table in dbtable?

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In [JDBC To Other Databases](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) I found the following explanation of `dbtable` parameter:

> The JDBC table that should be read. Note that anything that is valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example, instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses.

When I use the code:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
  dbtable "mytable"
)
```

everything works great, but the following:

```
 dbtable "SELECT * FROM mytable"
```

leads to the error:

[image]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since `dbtable` is used as a source for the `SELECT` statement it has be in a form which would be valid for normal SQL query. If you want to use subquery you should pass a query in parentheses and provide an alias:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
    url "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver",
    dbtable "(SELECT * FROM mytable) tmp"
);
```

It will be passed to the database as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable) tmp WHERE 1=0
```

Comment: What does "WHERE 1=0" signify?

Answer (score 0):

Code In Scala

```
val checkQuery = "(SELECT * FROM " + inputTableName + " ORDER BY " + columnName + " DESC LIMIT 1) AS timetable"

val timeStampDf = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("dbtable", checkQuery).load()
```

Adding an alias is also necessary after the query in parenthesis.