# How to use a subquery for dbtable option in jdbc data source?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I want to use Spark to process some data from a JDBC source. But to begin with, instead of reading original tables from JDBC, I want to run some queries on the JDBC side to filter columns and join tables, and load the query result as a table in Spark SQL.

The following syntax to load raw JDBC table works for me:

```
df_table1 = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url="jdbc:mysql://foo.com:3306",
    dbtable="mydb.table1",
    user="me",
    password="******",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" # mysql JDBC driver 5.1.41
).load() 
df_table1.show() # succeeded
```

According to Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) (I'm using PySpark 1.6.3):

> dbtable: The JDBC table that should be read. Note that anything that is valid
>   in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example, instead of a
>   full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses.

So just for experiment, I tried something simple like this:

```
df_table1 = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url="jdbc:mysql://foo.com:3306",
    dbtable="(SELECT * FROM mydb.table1) AS table1",
    user="me",
    password="******",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
).load() # failed
```

It threw the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table1 WHERE 1=0' at line 1
```

I also tried a few other variations of the syntax (add / remove parentheses, remove 'as' clause, switch case, etc) without any luck. So what would be the correct syntax? Where can I find more detailed documentation for the syntax? Besides, where does this weird "WHERE 1=0" in error message come from? Thanks!

Comment: From my point of view, you just have to specifiy the table you are trying to pull into spark so leave out the select statment. The 0=1 is derived from the parameter you didn't specify. Take a look at the source code of the [Dataframe Reader](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L207-L216)

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/32628717/1305344 looks similar but it's with PostgreSQL (not MySQL).

Answer (score 4):

For reading data from JDBC source using sql query in Spark SQL, you can try something like this:

```
val df_table1 = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
    ("url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb"),
    ("dbtable" -> "(select * from table1) as table1"),
    ("user" -> "me"),
    ("password" -> "******"),
    ("driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver"))
).load()
```

I tried it using PostgreSQL. You can modify it according to `MySQL`.

Comment: It seems I was doing the same thing as your answer, except I'm using python. Perhaps there is some syntax error on my code specific to PySpark?

Comment: You need to add the starting "(" and ending ")" around your query in Python. Also, you may have to end it with 't'. So something like this dbtable = "(<your_query_here>) t"

Answer (score 4):

```
table = "(SELECT id, person, manager, CAST(tdate AS CHAR) AS tdate, CAST(start AS   CHAR) AS start, CAST(end AS CHAR) as end, CAST(duration AS CHAR) AS duration FROM EmployeeTimes) AS EmployeeTimes",

spark = get_spark_session()
df = spark.read.format("jdbc"). \
    options(url=ip,
            driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
            dbtable=table,
            user=username,
            password=password).load()
return df
```

I had heaps of trouble with Spark JDBC incompatability with MYSQL timestamps. The trick is to convert all your timestamp or duration values to a string prior to having the JDBC touch them. Simply cast your values as strings and it will work.

Note: You will also have to use AS to give the query an alias for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

With Spark 2.2 on Python connecting to a MySQL (5.7.19) I'm able to run the following when I use `table="(SELECT * FROM a_table) AS my_table"`.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
    .builder.appName("myApp") \
    .config("jars", "/usr/local/spark-2.2.2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

my_df = my_spark.read.jdbc(
    url="jdbc:mysql://my_host:3306/my_db",
    table="(SELECT * FROM a_table) AS my_table",
    properties={'user': 'my_username', 'password': 'my_password'}
)

my_df.head(20)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be a bug in Spark SQL.

It *seems* that either [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L114) or [this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L101) gives you the error. Both use a Scala string interpolation to replace `table` with `dbtable`.

```
s"SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=0"
```

That's where you can find `table1 WHERE 1=0` from the error you've faced since the above pattern would become:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from table1) as table1 WHERE 1=0
```

which *looks* incorrect.

There is indeed a MySQL-specific dialect - [MySQLDialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/MySQLDialect.scala) - that overrides `getTableExistsQuery` with [its own](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/MySQLDialect.scala#L44-L46):

```
override def getTableExistsQuery(table: String): String = {
  s"SELECT 1 FROM $table LIMIT 1"
}
```

so my bet is that the other method [getSchemaQuery](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L113) is the source of the error. That's highly unlikely tough given you use Spark 1.6.3 while the method has `@Since("2.1.0")` marker.

I'd highly recommend checking out the logs of MySQL database and see what query is executed that leads to the error message.