# Spark read single column from PostgreSQL table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

## Question

Is there a way to load a specific column from a (PostreSQL) database table as a Spark DataFrame?

Below is what I've tried.

## Expected behavior:

The code below should result in *only* the specified column being stored in memory, not the entire table (table is too large for my cluster).

```
# make connection in order to get column names
conn = p2.connect(database=database, user=user, password=password, host=host, port="5432")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '%s'" % table)

for header in cursor:
    header = header[0]
    df = spark.read.jdbc('jdbc:postgresql://%s:5432/%s' % (host, database), table=table, properties=properties).select(str(header)).limit(10)
    # doing stuff with Dataframe containing this column's contents here before continuing to next column and loading that into memory
    df.show()
```

## Actual behavior:

Out of memory exception occurs. I'm presuming it is because Spark attempts to load the entire table *and then* select a column, rather than just loading the selected column? Or is it actually loading just the column, but that column is too large; I limited the column to just 10 values, so that shouldn't be the case?

```
2018-09-04 19:42:11 ERROR Utils:91 - uncaught error in thread spark-listener-group-appStatus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL query with one column only can be used in jdbc instead of "table" parameter, please find some details here:

[spark, scala & jdbc - how to limit number of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46984914/spark-scala-jdbc-how-to-limit-number-of-records/46993171#46993171)

Comment: I replaced the table argument with a query string: 'SELECT %s FROM %s' % (header, table). However, I get an error with the SELECT keyword from the postgresql driver. I noticed I can rewrite the read as spark.read.format('jdbc') and pass in the query string through the dbtable option, but is there a way to do this with the spark.read.jdbc function?

Comment: parentheses are important in such queries, please look: 
https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#push-down-a-query-to-the-database-engine

Comment: Thanks! The query string '(SELECT %s FROM %s) %s' % (header, table, header) did the trick.