# data extraction from oracle source

Tags: oracle, pyspark, extract, etl

I am trying to extract data from oracle source using pyspark.

I am using this code.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

> spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Spark_Job').getOrCreate()
>
> driver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
>
> url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXX'
>
> user = 'XXXXX'
>
> password = 'XXXXXXXX'
>
> query = 'SELECT col_1 from schema_1.view_1'
>
> df = spark.read.format('jdbc').option('driver', driver).option('url', url).option('dbtable', query)\
>
> .option('user', user).option('password', password).load()
>
> df.show(10)

I am getting this error :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00903: invalid table name
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a subquery for dbtable option in jdbc data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174838/how-to-use-a-subquery-for-dbtable-option-in-jdbc-data-source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORA-00903` means that you tried to use table name, but - that table doesn't exist.

There's only one `select` statement here:

```
SELECT col_1 from schema_1.view_1
                  -------- ------ 
                  owner    table (or view) name
                  ("user")
```

Info you posted suggests that you're connected as

```
user = 'XXXXX'
```

- If `view_1` belongs to currently connected user, you don't have to specify owner name so query would then be just `select col_1 from view_1`.
- If `view_1` belongs to currently connected user, then `view_1` must be correctly spelled. Oracle doesn't care about letter case **unless** you decided to enclose its (table's, view's) name into double quotes and used lower or mixed case - then you have to do it every time you reference that table, so query might be e.g. `select col_1 from "View_1"`.
- If `view_1` belongs to user who is different from currently logged user (that's what information you posted suggests), then yes - preceding table's name with its owner's name is the way to do it. **However**, `schema_1` (the owner) has to grant at least `select` privilege on `view_1` to `XXXXX` - otherwise, it won't work. (Double quotes/letter case issue still stands.)

I can't tell which situation of these you have, but now you have something to check and act appropriately.