# Undefined function: 'ST_GeomFromText' Using Spark / Java

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, geometry

I have the following dataframe

```
------------------------------------------------------
|longitude  | latitude  | geomType |    geom          |
------------------------------------------------------    
|-7.0737816 |33.82666166|Polygon   |[GEOMETRY - 113 o]|
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to apply this query on this dataframe

I use the folowing code

```
dataframe= sparkSession.sql("select ST_GeomFromText('POINT("+col("longitude")+" , '',"+col("latitude")+")')");
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ST_GeomFromText'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.
```

Note that I'm using java language on spark

I need your help .

Thank you

Comment: `ST_GeomFromText` is not defined, what did you expect? From where did you get that function?

Comment: I added the dependencies in pom.xml is it not enough?  '''geospark-sql''' dependencies

Comment: No, it's a Postgres extension. This function come from PostGIS, and it will not work if your database is not a geospatial database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable Postgis Query in Spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305560/how-to-enable-postgis-query-in-spark-sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ST\_geomfromtext function using Spark / java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830434/st-geomfromtext-function-using-spark-java)

Answer (score 0):

Since the ST_GeomFromText is not the part of org.apache.spark.sql.functions so it will not recognise it internally.
You need to first define the UDF for this function.
means you need to define the definition of that function and then register that function with spark as UDF then only you can use this function.
You can use following syntax:
`sqlContext.udf.register("ST_GeomFromText", <name of function or definition of function>)`

Thanks

Comment: I put for example a function which takes as parameter the two columns (longitude and latitude) of dataframe ?