# Spark Structured streaming: primary key in JDBC sink

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I am reading stream of data from kafka topic using strucured streaming with Update Mode., and then doing some transformation.

Then I have created a jdbc sink to push the data in mysql sink with Append mode. The problem is how do I tell my sink to let it know that this is my primary key and do the update based on it so that my table should not have any duplicate rows.

```
   val df: DataFrame = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<List-here>")
  .option("subscribe", "emp-topic")
  .load()


  import spark.implicits._
  // value in kafka is bytes so cast it to String
  val empList: Dataset[Employee] = df.
  selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .map(row => Employee(row.getString(0)))

  // window aggregations on 1 min windows
  val aggregatedDf= ......

  // How to tell here that id is my primary key and do the update
  // based on id column
  aggregatedDf
  .writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(60.seconds))
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Update)
  .foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
      batchDF
      .select("id", "name","salary","dept")
      .write.format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/empDb")
      .option("driver","com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")
      .option("dbtable", "empDf")
      .option("user", "root")
      .option("password", "root")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .save()
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is, you can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  with `foreachPartition` may serve this purpose

Below is the psuedo code snippet

```
/**
    * Insert in to database using foreach partition.
    * @param dataframe : DataFrame
    * @param sqlDatabaseConnectionString
    * @param sqlTableName
    */
  def insertToTable(dataframe: DataFrame, sqlDatabaseConnectionString: String, sqlTableName: String): Unit = {

//numPartitions = number of simultaneous DB connections you can planning to give
datframe.repartition(numofpartitionsyouwant)

    val tableHeader: String = dataFrame.columns.mkString(",")
    dataFrame.foreachPartition { partition =>
      // Note : Each partition one connection (more better way is to use connection pools)
      val sqlExecutorConnection: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlDatabaseConnectionString)
      //Batch size of 1000 is used since some databases cant use batch size more than 1000 for ex : Azure sql
      partition.grouped(1000).foreach {
        group =>
          val insertString: scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder = new scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder()
          group.foreach {
            record => insertString.append("('" + record.mkString(",") + "'),")
          }

val sql =   s"""
               | INSERT INTO $sqlTableName  VALUES  
               | $tableHeader
               | ${insertString}
               | ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
               | yourprimarykeycolumn='${record.getAs[String]("key")}'
    sqlExecutorConnection.createStatement()
                .executeUpdate(sql)
          }
    sqlExecutorConnection.close() // close the connection
        }
      }
```

you can use preparedstatement instead of jdbc statement.

Further reading : [SPARK SQL - update MySql table using DataFrames and JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640373/647053)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But that question you referred seems 3 years ago, so I am wondering if there is any other feature has to be in the current version of spark 2.4.0.

Comment: above approach will work with current version of spark as well since its RDD level

Comment: As of now I am marking the answer as accepted, as there is no other good alternative I found in spark.