# How to do the update and delete in spark with postgresql using java

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I am doing spark with postgresql, I can do the insert part in spark, but I can't do the update and delete.

Comment: hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/35640373/1025328