# Read and write to Aurora my sql inside glue

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I am trying to fetch csv files from s3 and push it to aurora, for now am using select and using dynamic frames writing it to aurora db

code to simple write from s3 to aurora (connection is already configured and mapped to glue job)

```
spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter",",").option("quote",'"').option("escape",'"').option("multiline","true").csv(s3_input_path).createOrReplaceTempView("transformed_data")

sql_query = """SELECT 
column1,column2
FROM transformed_data
"""

result_df = spark.sql(sql_query)

logging.info(f"result_dyf")
result_dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(result_df, glueContext, "result_dyf")

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(
    result_dyf, "my_saved_connection", 
    connection_options={"dbtable": "TARGETTABLE", "database": "DBNAME"}
    )
```

but now, i want to run updates/replace staments on top of my auroa my sql using glue.

I tried below code as above approach is not working for running queries but this is not able to establish connection with aurora mysql (db is configured within same AWS account as serverless with VPC and wanted to use custom jar)

```
mysql_jar_s3_location = "s3://your-bucket/mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar"

# Set the subnet ID and security group ID
subnet_id = "subnet-12345678"  # Replace with your actual subnet ID
security_group_id = "sg-12345678"  # Replace with your actual security group ID

# Set up Spark and Glue contexts
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

# Include the MySQL JDBC driver JAR file from S3 as a script library
spark._jsc.addJar(mysql_jar_s3_location)

# Specify the VPC, subnet, and security group details
vpc_config = {
    "SubnetIds": [subnet_id],
    "SecurityGroupIds": [security_group_id]
}

# Configure your Aurora MySQL connection options
aurora_connection_options = {
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://your-aurora-hostname:3306/your-database-name",
    "user": "your-username",
    "password": "your-password",
    "driver": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver",
    "vpcConfig": vpc_config
}

# Example SQL UPDATE query
update_query = "UPDATE your-table SET column1 = 'new-value' WHERE condition"

# Execute the UPDATE query
result_df = spark.sql(update_query)
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

As of now Spark DataFrame write do not support Upserts. Spark only support the below four save modes:

Overwrite,Append,Ignore,ErrorIfExists

In Glue Pyspark ETL, you can install the libraries like Odbc to perform the upsert operation (below example is for sqlserver, you can modify the code based on your Aurora mysql/postgre sql server):

```
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx:1433;databaseName=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx"
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="__TableInsert", mode='overwrite')
cnxn  = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;', autocommit=False) 
try:
    crsr = cnxn.cursor()
    # DO UPSERTS OR WHATEVER YOU WANT
    crsr.execute("DELETE FROM Table")
    crsr.execute("INSERT INTO Table (Field) SELECT Field FROM __TableInsert")
    cnxn.commit()
except:
    cnxn.rollback()
cnxn.close()
```

There is a [detailed answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634853/spark-sql-update-mysql-table-using-dataframes-and-jdbc) for this question in the forum.