# mysql table update using pyspark

Tags: mysql, pyspark, databricks

One of my requirements is to update one table that is present in a MySQL db. I am doing that like below:

```
update_query = f"""
    UPDATE {table_name}
    SET xxperc = 1.000
    WHERE xxID = ##########
"""
spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url1) \
    .option("dbtable", f"({update_query}) as update_query") \
    .option("user", username1) \
    .option("password", password1) \
    .load()
```

This throws an error like below:

> (conn=175897) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE questions

How can I fix this?

Comment: spark.read expects a query that returns data, not an update. You'll need to use another approach. see examples here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634853/spark-sql-update-mysql-table-using-dataframes-and-jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, updated below.

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=host,
    port=port,
    user=user,
    password=password,
    database=database
)
cursor = connection.cursor()
update_query = f""" """
cursor.execute(update_query)
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?