# How to connect (Py)Spark to Postgres database using JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have followed instructions from [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983982/how-to-use-jdbc-source-to-write-and-read-data-in-pyspark) to read data from an existing Postgres database with table named "objects" as defined and created by the `Objects` class in SQLalchemy. In my Jupyter notebook, my code is

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
from random import random

#spark conf
conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[*]")
conf.setAppName('pyspark')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
properties = {
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://PG_USER:PASSWORD@PG_SERVER_IP/db_name'
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(url=url, table='objects', properties=properties)
```

the last line results in the following:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.jdbc.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation.<init>(JDBCRelation.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.jdbc(DataFrameReader.scala:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

so it looks like it can't resolve the table. How do I test from here to make sure that I am connected to the database properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems with name resolving are indicated by `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException` and don't result in NPE. The source of the issue is actually a connection string and in particular the way you provide user credentials. At first glance it looks like a bug but if you're looking for a quick solution you can either use URL properties:

```
url = 'jdbc:postgresql://PG_SERVER_IP/db_name?user=PG_USER&password=PASSWORD'
```

or properties argument:

```
properties = {
    "user": "PG_USER",
    "password": "PASSWORD",
    "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
}
```