# How to safely pass credentials to jdbc interface in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, credentials

Questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983982/how-to-use-jdbc-source-to-write-and-read-data-in-pyspark) seem to indicate that a database can be queried directly from pyspark, I would like to update a data pipeline that uses sqoop to use this instead. But with sqoop you may use `-P` and your credentials will be hidden. I don't see how to use this for the jdbc interface, all the examples I can find suggest hardcoding usn/pass into the scripts. The data in my environment is sensitive so I cannot do this.

```
df = sqlCtx.load(source="jdbc",
                 url="jdbc:oracle:thin://x.x.x.x/xdb?user=****&password=****",
                 dbtable="somequery")
```

I have read that even libraries such as `getpass` which hide the input from the terminal are sometimes vulnerable to memory attacks. Is there a safe way to do this?