# connect to mysql from sparklyr and/or pyspark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, sparklyr

I am trying to connect to locally hosted mysql database. I tried two systems - R and Python.

Here is screenshot of my set .profile

[image]

and .bash_profile

[image]

Here is what I did:

- Tried to connect pyspark to local mysql, I get error see below (trace error of pyspark)

  Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
           in ()
                5 sparkClassPath = os.getenv('SPARK_CLASSPATH', '/Users/me/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar')
                6 sqlContext = SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
          ----> 7 sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:4040",driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",                                       dbtable = "product",user="root",password='').load()

  ```
      ~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
          163             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
          164         else:
      --> 165             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
          166 
          167     @since(1.4)

  ~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
     1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
     1132         return_value = get_return_value(
  -> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
     1134 
     1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

  ~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
       61     def deco(*a, **kw):
       62         try:
  ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
       64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
       65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

  ~/Documents/spark/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
      317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
      318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
  --> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
      320             else:
      321                 raise Py4JError(

  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o93.load.
  : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:38)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
      at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:78)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:34)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:307)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
      at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
      at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
      at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
      at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
      at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  ```
- Tried to connect to sparlyr to local mysql, I get error, see below (trace error of sparklyr)

trace error of sparklyr
[image]

**Question: How do I connect to mysql from either pyspark or sparklyr?**

Comment: For PySpark you'll find detailed instructions here: [How to use JDBC source to write and read data in (Py)Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983982/how-to-use-jdbc-source-to-write-and-read-data-in-pyspark)

Comment: thanks user9613318

Answer (score 0):

`SPARK_CLASSPATH` has been deprecated few years ago and is no longer supported. Assuming the jar contains a valid driver version use either:

- `spark.jars` configuration option.

or combined:

- `spark.driver.extraClassPath`
- `spark.executor.extraClassPath`

options.

Comment: thanks user9807949. How would I know which version is compatible? I am so terrified with the configuration. I am tying to do this in  Mac High Sierra 10.13.4