# how to read db format file in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
df_chinook = spark.read.format('jdbc').load("/content/datasets/chinook.db")
```

here is my code I try to load db base into pyspark dataframe, but have (error like this
IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Option 'url' is required.)
what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

##### Loading data from a JDBC source

```py
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

The JDBC URL of the form `jdbc:subprotocol:subname` to connect to. The source-specific connection properties may be specified in the URL.

e.g. `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret`

More data-sources examples [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983982/how-to-use-jdbc-source-to-write-and-read-data-in-pyspark) help you?
You could try with

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

SQLContext.read.jdbc(url="...", table="baz", properties=properties)
```